# Find the worst case number of times "Hello" is output

Tags: time-complexity, complexity-theory

I had this question on a quiz last week, and I don't understand how we were to have solved it. This is the question (see attached). Since there's nested for loops I see where the n^2 is coming from, but i'm not sure where the -n and the *.5 is coming from in the answer.

[image: Problem]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about computer science, not programming

Answer (score 1):

The "worst case" (if you can call printing a lot of hellos a "worst" case...) is when A is all zeros (for example), so all the <= evaluate to true.
But how many times does this loop run? It's **not** n^2: It's not n+n+n+n n times... Look at the inner loop! It's not from 1 to n-1 but rather from 1 to i. So the number of printouts is 1+2+3+...+(n-1). And that is exactly n*(n-1)/2, i.e., (n^2-n)/2. It's very easy to prove (Gauss did this as a little boy :-)), but since this a multiple-choice question, you can just test for one n.

If you're curious how to prove that X=1+2+3+...+(n-1) is n*(n-1)/2, here is Gauss's trick: Write X twice, in different order:

```
X = 1     +    2  +     3 + ... + (n-1)
X = (n-1) + (n-2) + (n-3) + ... + 1
```

Now sum up the two X's. Note how in each column you have two numbers summing up to n - 1+(n-1) is n, 2+(n-2) is n, and so on. So basically the entire sum has n-1 copies of n. So

```
2*X = n * (n-1)
```

So
    X = n*(n-1)/2

Which is exactly the (n^2-n)*0.5 you were looking to explain.